# Resetting the selected in a dropdown list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML select element, with a selected value which has a property of `display:none` on page load. The display changes to `block` when a button is clicked. 
And the select list is editable.

At this stage, if the user changes the selected value and then wants to reset it to the original one. Is there anyway I can do it?

*Solution I thought of:*

When the button is clicked, I can use the `selectedValue=$(#id).val()` to get the originally selected value. When cancelled I can use this selected value to set using `$(#id).val(selectedValue)`
But it doesn't work because I am not storing the `selectedValue`.

Is there some way to make this work? Is there some elegant solution for this?

Comment: You want clear the select box, when user presses the button?

Comment: You can't hide `<option>` tags in all browsers, notably IE. Not a good practice! Either disable or remove

Comment: @AnatoliyArkhipov: I have 2 buttons. When the user presses the 1st one, I let him change the selected value in the list. If he uses the 2nd button after that, I want to clear the values he selected and get back to the original value (the one I had on page load).

Comment: Can store initial value right on the select using jQuery data()

Comment: @charlietfl : It's inside a div and I am hiding the whole div. This part is working fine.

Comment: So, just store the initial value in some variable when page is loading, and put it to the select box when user presses the button. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cpeqvrer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, to make this work, you have to store this value somewhere. Can be in a variable, in a hidden, or you can use [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/), as pointed out in the comments.

On the pageload, you store the value. On the button's click, you get it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slt').data("originalValue", $('#slt').val());

    $('#reset').on('click', function() {
        $('#slt').val($('#slt').data("originalValue"));
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kf3vtzxh/1/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can use a

```
<input type="hidden" id="tempval">
```

and set the value to it during page load with the default this way you can compare it and reset it

like `$("#tempval").val()` whatever....